# Substract contents of one textfile from contents of another textfile on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, vim

I have two text files on Linux. One contains a list of valid IDs. E.g:

```
abcd
efgh
ijkl
etc.
```

The other contains a list of invalid IDs. But, some of these also appear on the list of valid IDs, in this example "efgh":

```
mnop
qrst
efgh
etc.
```

How can I easily construct a text file that contains all the lines from the invalid list that do not appear in the valid list? That is, I want to end up with a text file that has:

```
mnop
qrst
etc.
```

I'd like either some Linux commandline magic of some clever Vim trickery. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think **comm** can help you do what you want.

It is a less known command line tool that shall be present in most Linux systems.

Comment: Just what I needed. I used `comm -2 -3 invalid.txt valid.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have files named `valid` and `invalid`, you can sort them:

> sort valid > valid-sorted;  sort invalid > invalid-sorted

then compare:

> diff valid-sorted invalid-sorted

The output will be (assuming your example data):

```
1d0
< abcd
3c2,3
< ijkl
---
> mnop
> qrst
```

The stuff with '<' is only in the first file, the stuff with '>' only in the second (invalid).

Thus `diff valid-sorted invalid-sorted |grep '^>'` should give you the strings appearing in invalid but not in valid.

Stripping out the leading '>' is left as an exercise for the reader ;-).

Caveat: This will not work if your input files actually contain '>' at the start of a line. You'll have to do some tricking then...

Answer (score 0):

I have [my own utility](http://www.win.tue.nl/~rp/bin/except) for that, which relies on [another](http://www.win.tue.nl/~rp/bin/only); they also work on unsorted input.
Basic usage is

```
except file1 file2 > file2-except-any-lines-in-file1
```